# Javascript not rendering in Django app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

Deployed a Django app on Heroku, and after my home page, every page after does not render the Javascript file hosted on Amazon S3, but when opening Console in Inspect Element, it seems as if everything is loading fine. The header for my HTML file is below

```
#questions.html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/css/QandA.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/css/Button.css">
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/js/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/js/qanda.js"></script>
```

The file clearly works, but all the popup windows are already open when I load the page.

The only error is this

```
2XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/css/QandA.css. Origin http://warm-oasis-9454.herokuapp.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

2XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/css/Button.css. Origin http://warm-oasis-9454.herokuapp.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Anyone help me out?

EDIT:

Here is the page that works, the index

```
#index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/css/Index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/css/Button.css">
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/js/index.js"></script>
```

Also here is my CORS requirement for my s3 bucket

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>
            testsite.com
        </AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Is this any more helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, all I needed to do was reverse the order of the Javascript files and the CSS Files in the HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to enable cross origin resource sharing (CORS) on your S3 bucket, which Amazon (thankfully) added recently. Here's the docs: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html and also here http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html

Comment: ok. went to the amazon cors documentation, copied their example CORS configuration, changed the URL, <AllowedMethod> both GET and PUSH and saved the configuration in my bucket. Javascript still not working, any idea why?

Comment: @ChrisYin 'not working' isn't a problem description.  What error does it throw?

Comment: sorry. so the javascript file is not rendering, the dropdown buttons that are from the javascript file are all open when first rendering the page, as opposed to when you press the button. The same buttons referenced in the home page work, but not any pages after. Does that help?

Comment: I've noticed that your javascript is only referenced on the homepage, while the CSS is referenced on all other pages.

Comment: edited my question -- index.html is shown above now, this is the page that works. questions.html is the page that doesn't. also added my CORS configuration

Comment: have you added warm-oasis-9454.herokuapp.com as an entry in allowed origin?